# Custom image on navigation view item control does not display at run time

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I've created a Windows Template Studio (Universal Windows(UWP)) C# project, applying the navigation pane project type, with the MVVM basic design pattern, with a few pages to navigate to. I've substituted the default icons on the NavigationViewItem to custom images. However, even though the custom images with text display during design time, at run time, only the text is displayed and not the custom image.

When I tried removing the "x:Uid" (which I believe is also used by the Resources.resw file), the custom image with text would display, however, when clicking the NavigationViewItem control, the program stops/crashes at (in App.g.i.cs file):

```
#if DEBUG && !DISABLE_XAML_GENERATED_BREAK_ON_UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION
            UnhandledException += (sender, e) =>
            {
                if (global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached) global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
            };
#endif
```

Here is the xaml code:

```
<winui:NavigationViewItem x:Uid="Shell_AttentionList" helpers:NavHelper.NavigateTo="views:AttentionListPage" Height="75">
                 <winui:NavigationViewItem.Content>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Image Source="/Images/attentionList.png" />
                        <TextBlock Text=" Attention List" FontSize="16" FontFamily="segoe ui" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </winui:NavigationViewItem.Content>
</winui:NavigationViewItem>
```

Thanks

[As per requested (from Mahmudul Hasan) visual result expectation:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pis07.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

You can try this-

Using StackPanel [Not Recommended]

```
<NavigationViewItem>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Image Height="50"
               Margin="5"
               Source="Assets/bus.png"
               Stretch="Uniform"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Sample Text"/>
    </StackPanel>
</NavigationViewItem>
```

Using BitmapIcon [Recommended]

```
<NavigationViewItem Content="Sample Text" >
    <NavigationViewItem.Icon>
        <BitmapIcon UriSource="ms-appx:///Assets/bus.png"/>
    </NavigationViewItem.Icon>
</NavigationViewItem>
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Hasan. However, the stackpanel option is currently what I have, which doesn't work as originally explained. The navigation view item icon doesn't show the image clearly and larger.

Comment: @SM1012, if want to show the image clearly and larger you could scale Icon. Please refer this [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5fad9d91-5c36-420a-89d2-c2479d50c051/how-to-resize-symbolicon?forum=winappswithnativecode).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Nico Zhu. However, that only applies to a SymbolIcon, not to a BitmapIcon. Any other suggestions anyone?

Comment: Can you please visualize your expected result?

Comment: Hi Mahmudul Hasan, please see edit above with link to image of expected visual result. Thanks.

Comment: Hi! I created a project on MVVM basic,  and strangely the code didn't work. I don't know why. But it entirely worked on a standard project. So you were right at your first comment. Strange! 

Comment: Exactly. It only displays at design time(when using image element in stackpanel), but not at run time. Not sure if the "x:Uid" attribute which is tied to he resource file "Resources.resw" is affecting it at run time. Anyone? Any help would be appreciated.